# GridView row won't disable

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am trying to disable a specific grdview row using the code below, but it isn't disabling that row. I am 100% sure there is a value called "Total Expenses" in the column that is bound to the gridview. What is more strange is that, I  removed the if condition(accountTextBox.Text == "Total Expenses") to see if all the rows get disabled but only the first row is getting disabled. Any thoughts on this?

More information: Am using gridview with template fields(ASP.NET, C#). I also ran debugger and found that the **accountTextBox** is showing NULL. Am puzzled!

I appreciate any thoughts you may have. Thank you

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        if (!tableCopied)
        {
            originalDataTable = ((System.Data.DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem).Row.Table.Copy();
            ViewState["originalValuesDataTable"] = originalDataTable;
            tableCopied = true;
            TextBox accountTextBox = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("AccountTextBox");

                if (accountTextBox.Text == "Total Expenses")
                {
                    e.Row.Enabled = false;
                }

        }
}
```

Comment: Where is tableCopied being set?  There's potential that the value isn't persisting through PostBacks.

Comment: Thanks Garrison, The following lines are right above the code block I posted before:                                                                       `public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private bool tableCopied = false;
    private System.Data.DataTable originalDataTable;`

Comment: can you post the template markup

Comment: also - variables do not persist unless saved/restored to/from viewstate or session state

Comment: He doesn't need to persist them since he is setting tableCopied manually to false in the code-behind.

Comment: @sam : also - by removing that if statement as you did, it is correct that only the first row would be disabled. after the first row you set the flag to true and so never enter that outer if again

Comment: @Garrison : if all he needs is one pass, that's fine.  just trying to be clear that `tableCopied` is not persisted.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming your markup looks something like this:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="SomeField" SortExpression="SomeField">
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="AccountTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("SomeField") %>'></asp:TextBox>
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("SomeField") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

In which case `AccountTextBox` will only be available in RowDataBound when e.Row.State is in Edit mode.  which may or may not be available depending what update functionality is provided in your datasource...but that's something else.

Typically you don't use a TextBox to display data but lets say trying to populate a "readonly" TextBox then all you need do is move AccountTextBox from the EditTemplate to the ItemTemplate and you should be good to go.

Comment: This is a valid point, but if it were the case, his code that checks the value of `accountTextBox.Text` would throw a null reference exception.

Comment: True. Although he didn't say it explicitly, he did state the value of `accountTextBox` was null...conclusion?

Comment: Upped you--completely forgot about his mention of null.

Comment: :) you're a good man. Cute cat by the way. Nice chatting with you.

Answer (score 0):

The `tableCopied` variable could be the problem. It will be set to true on the first row and this will restrict the remaining rows to enter the if condition and actually be disabled.

```
First row:   
  //tableCopied is false
  if(!tableCopied) // pass
      tableCopied = true

Other rows:
  //tableCopied is true
  if(!tableCopied) // wont pass
```

Note that the `GridView1_RowDataBound` event occurs once for every row on the same postback and every class member is persisted during the postback.

Answer (score 0):

Using the following code-behind:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            gvTest.DataSource = new List<string>() { "test1", "test2" };
            gvTest.DataBind();
        }

        private bool tableCopied = false;
        private System.Data.DataTable originalDataTable;

        protected void gvTest_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                if (!tableCopied)
                {
                    //originalDataTable = ((System.Data.DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem).Row.Table.Copy();
                    //ViewState["originalValuesDataTable"] = originalDataTable;
                    //tableCopied = true;
                    TextBox accountTextBox = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("AccountTextBox");

                    if (accountTextBox.Text == "Total Expenses")
                    {
                        e.Row.Enabled = false;
                    }

                }
        }
    }
```

And this markup:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gvTest" OnRowDataBound="gvTest_RowDataBound">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="AccountTextBox" runat="server">Total Expenses</asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

I am not reproducing the bug.  Both rows disable for me.

Comment: something to check - if he actually placed a textbox in a template markup ItemTemplate - that's one thing.  If he converted a bound field  to template, I believe it places a label in the ItemTemplate and a textBox in the EditTemplate.  I could be wrong, but I don't think your going to find the textBox unless the Gridview is in edit mode, which is why I wanted to see his markup.

Comment: Thanks so much guys, all the suggestions worked. Am so glad to be part of this community. Hope I'll start paying back soon :)                     I am not bale to mark your posts as answer, moderators, can you please help?

Comment: That's ok - I was in the middle of posting my thoughts when you commented - glad we all put you in the right direction.